# Checking if dynamically created checkbox is selected using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table containing checkboxes. I add checkboxes to a table whenever a button is clicked as follows:

```
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="checkBox" value=\"selected?\" style="cursor:pointer" value="htcb"/>';
```

How can I find out if the checkbox in, say cell 3, is selected?

I've tried this

```
var myCheckBox = row.cells[2].innerHTML;
   if(myCheckBox .checked == true)
      //
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Why should `higherTierCB` point to your checkbox? Is there code missing?

Comment: No worries. And to be browser compatible it would be wise to use a library like jQuery for creating and checking dom elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `innerHTML` property is just a string, you need to access the DOM object itself.

Seeing as the `<input>` is the only thing in the cell, this should work:

```
var myCheckBox = row.cells[2].firstChild;
if (myCheckBox.checked) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

js function:

```
function check() {
     if($(this).is(”:checked”))
     {
         alert(’checked’);
     }
}
```

you must add onchange listener:

```
cell3.innerHTML = '<input type="checkBox" value=\"selected?\" 
               style="cursor:pointer"value="htcb" onchange="check()"/>';
```

Comment: There is no mentioning of jQuery